# DNS Url Redirecting

Tags: url, dns, redirect

I've built a landing page for my personal website which says that I'm currently unavailable to take any extra work. Let's say this page's url is http://example.com/unavailable

I have a few other domains which I own which function as working websites. They also have a page on them with a URL similar to http://otherurl.com/creator

How would I create a DNS record on http://otherurl.com so that if a user visited the page *http://otherurl.com/creator* they would be redirected to http://example.com/unavailable?

Comment: You can’t do this with DNS. This would be in the configuration of either your web servers or application servers, depending on how your sites are deployed and configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, DNS only concerns the name part, i.e. until `.com`.  Therefore it can only redirect whole `otherurl.com` – or `creator.otherurl.com` but I don't think you want to structure your web that way...